# Using BIDS to extract data from Informix ODBC source with parameters

Tags: ssis, odbc, informix, bids

As it says in the title, I am trying to extract data from my Informix ODBC source with parameters. I have two parameters that i am trying to pass. Both are DateTime and i am trying to get the current starting date for example `2014-10-10 00:00:00` and the ending date `2014-10-10 23:59:59`.

If i do this with a normal query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE STARTDATETIME BETWEEN '2014-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-10 23:59:59'
```

Everything works fine. However, if I try and use the parameters that I have set up:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE STARTDATETIME BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I get the following error:

```
Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '07001'. 
Native Error Code: -11012. [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Wrong number of parameters.
```

I feel like it has to do with my query, but I have been looking and have found nothing. Would anyone be able to help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use parameterized query ('?') binding is needed. 
Likely you may be using ODBC API SQLBindCol  for binding it.
The number of parameter in the query (in this case it is 2) 
should be matching with number of bind API calls.
Please check your ODBC code to make sure the binding is correctly done.